# Importing CSV relations to Neo4j

Tags: mysql, csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import data from a MySQL database to Neo4j, using CSV files as an intermediary.  I'm following the [basic example](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/), but can't quite get it to work.  I'm importing two tables with these queries:

```
//Import projects.
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/projects.csv" AS row
CREATE (:project
{
     project_id: row.fan,
     project_name: row.project_name
});

//Import people.
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/persons.csv" AS row
CREATE (:person
{
     person_id: row.person_id,
     person_name: row.person_name,
});

//Create indicies.
CREATE INDEX ON :project(project_id);
CREATE INDEX ON :project(project_name);
CREATE INDEX ON :person(person_id);
CREATE INDEX ON :person(person_name);
```

This part works.  What doesn't work is when I try to import the relations:

```
//Create project-person relationships.
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/project_persons.csv" AS row
MATCH (project:project {project_id: row.project_id})
MATCH (person:person {person_id: row.person_id})
MERGE (person)-[:CONTRIBUTED]->(project);
```

The console accepts the query without an error, but never finishes.  It's been running for days at 100% CPU, 25% RAM, but negligible disk usage.  No relations appear in the database information.

Did I make a mistake somewhere, or is it really this slow?  The `project_persons.csv` file is 13 million lines long, but shouldn't the periodic commit make something show up by now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shouldn't the periodic commit make something show up by now?
```

Only for the LOAD - do an "explain" at the front of the CREATE and it'll tell you how it's structuring the update and the # of records it expects to process. I ran into the same issue - Neo4j was doing the entire update as a single transaction and never completed. The transaction needed to be broken up into 50K - 100K tx  chunks to get everything done.

One way to do thisis to import the relation information as a set of labelled nodes, and then use those nodes to MATCH() the person and project nodes and create the relation as required.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/project_persons.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Relations {project_id: row.project_id, person_id: row.person_id})
```

then process the records in 50K batches:

```
MATCH (r:Relations) 
MATCH (prj:project {project_id: r.project_id})
MATCH (per:person {person_id: r.person_id})
WITH r, prj, per LIMIT 50000
MERGE (per)-[:CONTRIBUTED]->(prj)
DELETE r
```

Run this multiple times until all the relations are created and you're good to go.

Comment: It works, but importing all the data is tedious, even when I increased the limit.  And for some reason I have 200k relations left over which won't merge or delete.

Comment: Agreed on being tedious. What are you doing to delete the unwanted relations?

Comment: I don't know what to do with them, or even if they are unwanted.

Comment: If this works, then please mark it as the answer so I get some rep pts. Thx!